# EL expression in custom tag parameter name

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I created custom tag for encoding and rewriting URLs with dynamic parameters. For ex.:

```
<mytags:outUrl url="${value1}" id="${value2}" />
```

works as expected (`url` is standard parameter and `id` is first dynamic parameter).

Is it possible to also have dynamic parameter names like this directly?

```
<mytags:outUrl url="${var1}" ${name1}="${var2}" />
```

I know it is possible to use `<jsp:attribute>` but it is too much code:

```
<mytags:outUrl url="${var1}"><jsp:attribute name="${name1}">${var2}</jsp:attribute></mytags:outUrl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reinventing the JSTL, which already has a standard tag to do that:

```
<c:url value="${someUrl}">
    <c:param name="${someName}" value="${someValue}"/>
    <c:param name="${someOtherName}" value="${someOtherValue}"/>
</c:url>
```

To answer your question: no, the syntax you propose isn't supported. The closest to what you're suggesting is dynamic attributes. See http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/dynamic-attributes-in-tag-file-in-jsp-2-0/ and http://www.coderanch.com/t/170429/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/Tutorial-Dynamic-Attributes for examples.

Comment: yes, I would like to use <c:url>, but it doesnt encode the url (for ex. translate & to &amp; etc...). thats why I created custom tag..

Comment: You could simply use the `var` attribute of c:url to store the URL in a page-scope var, and use c:out to html-escape the generated URL.

Comment: I agree this is a bit cumbersome, but 99% of URLs don't have more than one parameter, in my experience. That said, if you want to write a tag for that, just follow the same design as the JSTL design: this will make your tag easy to use by everyone already knowing the JSTL.